# How can I get the libncursesw.so.6 file? Install is "up to date" but files do not exist

Tags: linux, gdb, ncurses

I recently went to try to debug a program with GDB and got the following error: 
`gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libncursesw.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So I went investigating and tried the obvious things, ie `sudo apt-get install libncursesw5` (and dev variants) and apt reports that I've already got the latest version...so next I tried reinstalling GDB, problem persists. The output of ldd with GDB confirms to me that it still doesn't know where this mythical `libncursesw.so.6` file is, so I go digging around in the `usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` folder and run `ls libncu*` which returns six results: `libncurses.a`, `libncurses++.a`, `libncurses.so`, `libncurses++w.a`, `libncursesw.a`, and `libncursesw.so`...but no `libncursesw.so.6`. I then naively attempted to just make a copy of `libncursesw.so` named `libncursesw.so.6`, to which gdb reports that this file is "too short".

In googling I can't seem to find a good explanation on how to get this file in place? Every other answer I see just suggests running `sudo apt-get install libncursesw5` (or something similar) but I've already tried pretty much every variant of that I can think of. I was going to remove it and then reinstall it but when I went to do that it gave me a scary warning that I could be doing something potentially harmful to my system so I aborted that idea.

Some context that also might(?) help: 
I'm running a pretty recent install of Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon, and this was my first time trying to run GDB on my new computer. I basically set this new computer up as a new install, just porting over my home directory and a couple of the more useful hidden . files from my old laptop...I figure this shouldn't be the reason GDB is failing/these files don't exist on the new machine but just in case I'm mentioning it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> obvious things, ie `sudo apt-get install libncursesw5`

You want `libncursesw6`, not `libncursesw5`.

Comment: Thanks -- I suppose that should have been obvious. I was put off because this version wasn't in my default repositories, but adding the repository and installing this version as you suggested did indeed fix it. Sorry for the dumb question!